# how to use C++ code in Swift for iOS

Tags: c++, ios, swift

I want to use C++ codes in swift for iOS.
Although I have learnt how to do that at stackoverflow,it is still a problem for me.

code for ccc.cpp:

```
#include "ccc.h"
int main(){
    int a = 0;
    return a;
}
```

code for ccc.h:

```
#ifndef __cplus__ccc__
#define __cplus__ccc__

#include <stdio.h>
int main();
#endif /* defined(__cplus__ccc__) */
```

code for bridging header:

```
//
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
//

#include"ccc.h"
```

After this I still can not use main() in my ViewController.swift.
Is there anyone would like to help me?

Comment: Could you be more specific than "can not use"?

Comment: thx all the same I have solved this problem.:)

Answer (score 3):

You can't use inline C/C++ methods in Swift, you have to create a wrapper in either Objective-C or Objective-C++.

The [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/index.html) states:

> You cannot import C++ code directly into Swift. Instead, create an
>   Objective-C or C wrapper for C++ code.

Comment: It's quite troublesome to use c++ class in Swift not like in Objective-C. Have to write a Objective-C Wrapper first, then a Swift wrapper.